# Using bash to parse data from log files?

Tags: bash, sed, grep

My log file looks something like this:

```
<lun compNum="3" partitionNum="1" failed="1" backup="1" free_mem="1024" max_mem="2048" />
<lun compNum="22" partitionNum="11" failed="1" backup="0" free_mem="1024" max_mem="2048" />
```

I want a output that goes through all of those lines and saves the pair of `compNum` and `paritionNum` into this:

`PAIR=($compNumValue parititonNumValue)`

A solution without using any external libraries and only using native bash would be ideal. Any idea how to get started for someone who is new to bash?

Comment: If these log files are valid XML, the best approach is far and away to use an XML-aware consumer. Anything else **will** be prone to bugs: There are many cases where the same XML text can be written multiple ways (or can have completely different meanings depending on context), but a consumer written without knowing the language will only recognize one of them.

Comment: StackOverflow is about helping people fix their programming code. Requests for free coding services, tutorials, research, tools, recommendations, and libraries are off-topic.  ***Please*** read  http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask , http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask ,  http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve  and take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) before posting more Qs here. Good luck.

Comment: ...and [stackoverflow/jobs](https://stackoverflow.com/jobs) if you want to hire a coder.

Comment: @shellter I'm not asking for anyone to do the code for me, but rather someone help point me in the right direction because google hasn't gotten me far. Please note that my question says: 'Any idea how to get started for someone who is new to bash?'

Comment: BTW, if you really want a pair, use quotes. `pair=( "$compNumValue" "$partitionNumValue" )` -- otherwise, you have no guarantees whatsoever about how many elements each expansion turns into. (Also, all-caps variable names are used by variables with meaning to the shell or operating system, whereas names with at least one lower-case character are guaranteed not to conflict with those used by the shell or POSIX-specified OS tools; see http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap08.html, paragraph four).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### The Wrong Way (What You Asked For)

```
lun_re='<lun compNum="([[:digit:]]+)" partitionNum="([[:digit:]]+)"[^/]* />'
while IFS= read -r line; do
  if [[ $line =~ $lun_re ]]; then
    compNum=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
    partitionNum=${BASH_REMATCH[2]}
    echo "Read a line with compNum $compNum and partitionNum $partitionNum"
  fi
done
```

See:

- [BashFAQ #1](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001) - *How can I read a file (data stream, variable) line-by-line (and/or field-by-field)?*
- [The BashGuide on Regular Expressions](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/Patterns#Regular_Expressions-1) - explaining `BASH_REMATCH` and `[[ $string =~ $regex ]]`

---

#### The Right Way

Use an XML parser when reading XML. **Really**. Anything else won't know how to deal with comments, namespaces, CDATA sections, or even simple changes like a new version of the program generating this log putting all the elements on the same line (or putting newlines between the attributes, or even just changing the attributes to have `partitionNum` come before `partNum`).

In this context, that might look like:

```
while IFS='|' read -r -d '' compNum partitionNum; do
  echo "Read a line with compNum $compNum and partitionNum $partitionNum"
done < <(xmlstarlet sel -t -m '//lun[@compNum][@partitionNum]' \
           -v ./@compNum -o '|' \
           -v ./@partitionNum -n)
```

In addition to the links given above, see [BashFAQ #24](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/024) to understand why the `< <(...)` syntax is in use.

If you don't have XMLStarlet installed on the systems where this is being run, you can generate an XSLT template and use `xsltproc` to evaluate it. `xmlstarlet -C` emits the following XSLT as equivalent to the above command:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:exslt="http://exslt.org/common" version="1.0" extension-element-prefixes="exslt">
  <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="no"/>
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:for-each select="//lun[@compNum][@partitionNum]">
      <xsl:call-template name="value-of-template">
        <xsl:with-param name="select" select="./@compNum"/>
      </xsl:call-template>
      <xsl:text>|</xsl:text>
      <xsl:call-template name="value-of-template">
        <xsl:with-param name="select" select="./@partitionNum"/>
      </xsl:call-template>
      <xsl:value-of select="'&#10;'"/>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template name="value-of-template">
    <xsl:param name="select"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="$select"/>
    <xsl:for-each select="exslt:node-set($select)[position()&gt;1]">
      <xsl:value-of select="'&#10;'"/>
      <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

...such that you can use `xsltproc /path/to/template.xslt -` as equivalent to the given `xmlstarlet` command.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation and links above, super valuable things to know. I am trying to get the above script to work but I'm having trouble. Here is what I'm doing to pass in the file: `cat /location/of/file | while IFS= read -r line; do` this prints empty values for `compNum` and `partitionNum`. Any idea what I could be doing wrong? (Will also try and implement your second solution when I have the first working.)

Comment: Better to put `< /location/of/file` after the `done`. Piping to a `while` loop triggers the bug discussed in [BashFAQ #24](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/024), preventing you from being able to use the captured values after the loop exits.

Comment: @khalessi22, ...otherwise, though, that was my bug -- the regex was missing capture groups. I've edited to add them; see the updated code.